# Guardar opciones marcadas AlertDialog Multichoice

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, alertdialog

Pues ya afinando la App que estoy desarrollando me encuentro en un pequeño dilema.

Bueno al grano, tengo una pantalla que se llama cliente ahí muestro una lista de clientes, y en la parte de `ActionBar` tengo un botón el cual me hace un `AlertDialog` MultiChoice el cual debo de seleccionar las zonas que visitaré.

Hasta ese punto todo esta bien, yo todos esos datos los obtengo desde un `WebServices`.

Mi duda es que necesito cuando yo seleccione una opciones de mi MultiChoice se guarde eso en el `SharedPreferences` y cuando yo vuelva a dar Tap en el botón del filtro me muestro lo último que tenia seleccionado.

Les dejo el código donde genero mi `AlertDialog` MultiChoice

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList){
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

            final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
            // zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
            for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
                //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
                zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();
                // zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getClave();
            }
            final boolean[] selCrayons={true,false,true};
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Selecciona la(s) Zonas a Visitar");
            dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(zona,selCrayons,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(arg2) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zona Seleccionada " + zona[arg1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Mandar a llamar metodo Clientes con el filtro

                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog=dialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Aclaro uso la clase `Asynctask` para el llamado del `WebService`.

Comment: alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

La línea `final boolean[] selCrayons={true,false,true};` que se ejecuta cada que creas el `AlertDialog` es la que hace que se seleccionen siempre las mismas casillas. Independientemente de que no entiendo porqué consultarías siempre el web service, te propongo esta solución:

1. Hacer variable global el arreglo.

   ```
   private boolean[] selCrayons = {true, false, true};
   ```
2. Clonar el arreglo, para no modificar los valores si se oprime Cancelar

   ```
   protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList){
       final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
       // zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
       for(int i=0; i < ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
           //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
           zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();
           // zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getClave();
       }
       final boolean[] selCrayonsTemp = selCrayons.clone();
       AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
       dialog.setTitle("Selecciona la(s) Zonas a Visitar");
       dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(zona, selCrayonsTemp, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
               selCrayonsTemp[arg1] = arg2;
               if(arg2) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zona Seleccionada " + zona[arg1],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
       });
       dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               selCrayons = selCrayonsTemp;
           }
       });
       dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
       AlertDialog alertDialog=dialog.create();
       alertDialog.show();
   }
   ```

Comment: ok, gracias por el apoyo

Comment: una pregunta como puedo yo obtener el item seleccionado y mandarlo por intent para mandarlo a otro activity?

Comment: amigo no entendi bien lo de clonar el arreglo, me puedes explicar?

Comment: Para lo del intent, deberías de hacer otra publicación.

En la líne `final boolean[] selCrayonsTemp = selCrayons.clone();` clonamos el arreglo, ya que el original no se debería de actualizar hasta que presiones "Ok". Si no lo hicieras así, llegas a modificar las casillas y presionas "Cancelar", de todas formas se guardan los cambios.